# Хороший материал по битовым полям

Tags: битовые-операции, c, c++

Подскажите хороший материал по битовым полям. Я знаю, что в интернете много про это написано, но хотелось бы что-то максимально понятное, где хорошо объясняется.

Comment: А что в них непонятно ?

Comment: Если честно, то вообще не имею представления о них. Хочется подробное что-то по ним. Как применять и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть очень хорошая книжка, называется Hackers Delight, Henry S. Warren. На русском она называется "Алгоритмические трюки для программистов". Примерно половина книги посвящена различным битовым операциям.

Answer (score 5):

Битовое поле
Материал из Википедии — свободной энциклопедии

```
struct rgb {
    int       r:2;
    int       g:2;
    unsigned  b:5;
    int       x:2;
    long long y:62;
};

main ()
{
    struct rgb c1;

    c1.r = 1;
    c1.g = 3;
    c1.x = 2;
    c1.b = 31;
    printf ("Hello %d\n",sizeof(c1));
    printf ("%d %d %d %d\n",c1.r,c1.g,c1.b,c1.x);
}
```

Вообще это целые с заданной Вами разрядностью (после двоеточия). gcc упаковывает их в массив int[] (по 32 разряда) или long long[] (по 64 разряда) в зависимости от максимальной длины поля (максимально длинное поле должно уместиться в int или long long), именуемый структурой. Для 64-х разрядного компилятора не знаю, м.б. все в long long.

Поиграйтесь цифирками и все увидите.